# Strange urllib2.urlopen() error with variable vs string

Tags: python, urllib2

I am having some strange behavior while using urllib2 to open a URL and download a video.

I am trying to open a video resource and here is an example link:

```
https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/o/20130723/b3ed92cc582885e27cb5c8d8b51b9956/b740dc57c2a44ea2dc2d940d93d772e2.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI456JQ76GBU7FECA&Signature=S3lvi9n9kHbarCw%2FUKOknfpkkkY%3D&Expires=1374639361
```

I have the following code:

```
        mp4_url = ''
        #response_body is a json response that I get the mp4_url from
        if response_body['outputs'][0]['label'] == 'mp4':
            mp4_url = response_body['outputs'][0]['url']

        if mp4_url:
            logging.info('this is the mp4_url')
            logging.info(mp4_url)

            #if I add the line directly below this then it works just fine
            mp4_url = 'https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/o/20130723/b3ed92cc582885e27cb5c8d8b51b9956/b740dc57c2a44ea2dc2d940d93d772e2.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI456JQ76GBU7FECA&Signature=S3lvi9n9kHbarCw%2FUKOknfpkkkY%3D&Expires=1374639361'

            mp4_video = urllib2.urlopen(mp4_url)
            logging.info('succesfully opened the url')
```

The code works when I add the designated line but it gives me a HTTP Error 403: Forbidden message when I don't which makes me think it is messing up the mp4_url somehow.  But the confusing part is that when I check the logging line for mp4_url it is exactly what I hardcoded in there.  What could the difference be?  Are there some characters in there that may be disrupting it?  I have tried converting it to a string by doing:

```
mp4_video = urllib2.urlopen(str(mp4_url))
```

But that didn't do anything.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:

With the suggestion to use print repr(mp4_url) it is giving me:

```
u'https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/o/20130723/b3ed92cc582885e27cb5c8d8b51b9956/b740dc57c2a44ea2dc2d940d93d772e2.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI456JQ76GBU7FECA&Signature=S3lvi9n9kHbarCw%2FUKOknfpkkkY%3D&Expires=1374639361'
```

And I suppose the difference is what is causing the error but what would be the best way to parse this?

UPDATE II:

It ended up that I did need to cast it to a string but also the source that I was getting the link (an encoded video) needed nearly a 60 second delay before it could serve that URL so that is why it kept working when I hardcoded it because it had that delay.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: After your logging calls, what happens when you try             `assert mp4_url == 'https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/o/20130723/b3ed92cc582885e27cb5c8d8b51b9956/b740dc57c2a44ea2dc2d940d93d772e2.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI456JQ76GBU7FECA&Signature=S3lvi9n9kHbarCw%2FUKOknfpkkkY%3D&Expires=1374639361'` ?

Comment: I did an if statement to see if they are the same and they are != but I am not sure what could be causing the difference or how to find out

Comment: `print repr(mp4_url)`. That'll give you a good idea of exactly what you're dealing with.

Comment: good idea, just updated it

Comment: Try `logging.info(type(mp4_url))`, `logging.info(len(mp4_url))`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to simply dump the response obtained. This way you would be able to check what response_body['outputs'][0]['label'] evaluates to. In you case, you are initializing mp4_url to ''. This is not the same as None and hence the condition `if mp4_url:` will always be true.

You may want to check that the initial **if** statement where you check that response_body['outputs'][0]['label'] is correct.

Comment: that is statement is correct and I corrected the initialization to None but the problem is that the mp4_url string is surrounded by u'string' I'm just not sure how to fix that...

Comment: I am of the opinion that the 'u' before the URL should not create a problem. I tried a simple test on my python interpreter where I did something like urllib2.urlopen(u'<some_url>') and it worked well.